# Protobuf, Python: assign to a field

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I am trying to modify values in a protobuf binary file with Python. I iterate over the fields in the message and set them to new values, however, when I check the values in the message object, I see that the values are still the same, which leads me to the conclusion that the fields are copied during the iteration.

Is there a way to modify fields in a protobuf message without creating a new object and assembling it from modified values?

**UPD**: I am working with a parsed binary file, that is I import my generated python file (generated from the .proto file), `ParseFromString` it, and then I work with the deserialized representation of that.

Comment: Let me understand better: you are parsing the [binary wire format](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding)? How are you doing it? Saved the blob in memory array? Having some kind of stream processing?

Comment: Updated the question itself with the answer to your question.

Comment: You would need to show the iteration/mutation code

Comment: Turns out, when i do things like `b = proto.cont[0].element[2]`, I get a copy of the element of the datastructure, not a reference to it, so my modifications don't count, as it were. Now I'm rewriting my code such that I do not copy things.

Comment: "_Updated the question itself with the answer to your question._" This is an internet evolution of Rubberduck Debugging, called The StackOverflow Effect.

Comment: Well, I thought I should write something, so I wrote this. Thank you for your replies anyway.